# Exclude architectural services from being processed by aspect

Tags: spring, aspectj, spring-aop

I'm creating an aspect to wrap my services but I'm also defining some services under the package

```
com.foo.arch
```

My application classes will be instead under

```
com.foo
```

Please notice that arch is a subpackage of com.foo but I can't put the "arch" keyword before.Isn't there a pointcut expression to say:

> All classess under com.foo not having "arch" as third package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider an interface `SampleService`

```java
  public interface SampleService {
        void test();
    }
```

and has 3 implementations in these three package

```java
com

com.foo

com.foo.arch
```

an aspect to exclude `arch` package and only advice classes under `com` and `com.foo` would be as follows

```java
@Component
@Aspect
public class ExcludeAspect {

    @Around("execution(* test()) && !within(com.foo.arch.*)")
    public void adviceTestMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Adviced");
        pjp.proceed();
    }
}
```

Reference : 
[within](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-pointcuts-designators)

[Combining Pointcut Expressions](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-pointcuts-combining)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

How about adding this to your pointcut?

```
within(com.foo..*) && !within(com.foo.arch..*)
```

This will capture all sub-packages of `com.foo` except for `com.foo.arch` and its respective sub-packages.

If you only want `com.foo` and no sub-packages at all, it would simply be:

```
within(com.foo.*)
```